# How can I retrieve 1 row at a time from a db on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm developing an item picking system and need to iterate through a table one item at a time on the click of a button. Currently, the button only retrieves and displays the first item in the table. How can I change it so it iterates through each one at a time when I click the button? Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Here's my php file to retrieve data

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"items");


$sql="SELECT * FROM items Limit 1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);
```

And here's my button

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#button1').click(function (e) {
    $.getJSON("getItem.php", function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
         $("#div1").empty();
        $("#div1").append(JSON.stringify(result));     //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to maintain a variable to handle the offset for the LIMIT query. You can try this way,

**JS Code :**

```
<script>
var offset = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#button1').click(function (e) {
    // pass offset value with GET request
    $.getJSON("getItem.php?offset=" + offset, function(result){

      offset++; // increment the value after successful AJAX call
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
         $("#div1").empty();
        $("#div1").append(JSON.stringify(result));     //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**PHP Code :**

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"items");

// Get the offset value
$offset = empty($_GET['offset']) ? 0 : $_GET['offset']

$sql="SELECT * FROM items Limit 1, $offset"; // pass the offset value to LIMIT query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried this and i keep getting an error in my php file: xdebug-error xe-warning: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given. for some reason it doesn't like the offset variable in the sql statement because when i delete it the error goes away

Comment: I have forgotten to put a , to separate the offset from limit. I have updated the answer check if it works now.

Comment: thank you, i'm getting an error of undefined variable for rows now.

Comment: i've managed to fix that, however each time i try to iterate through each record one by one with the button, it will add the next item in the table onto the last

Answer (score 1):

I would put an attribute in button1 to keep track of the count.

```
<div id="button1" count="1">clickme</div>
```

In your javascript, add code to find that count and send it in your request to your PHP page.

```
('#button1').click(function (e) {
var thisCount = document.getElementById('button1').getAttribute('count');
// don't forget to increase that count for the next time
document.getElementById('button1').setAttribute('count', (thisCount + 1));
$.getJSON("getItem.php?count=" + thisCount, function(result){
// ... rest of code
```

In your PHP page, I have to assume you have some kind of ID as the key.  item_id = 1, item_id = 2, etc.  Change the query to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = ".$_GET['count'].";"
```